# Is it possible to enter Dart code directly into the Chromium Dev Tools Console?

Tags: dart, dartium

I am running the latest Chromium build, with the Dart VM.  I would like to start playing with Dart's HTML library by messing around with websites, using the Console to enter Dart commands. Obviously, this is easy with Javascript, but I can't work out how to tell the console that I am entering Dart, not JS.

Is this possible?

Comment: Apparently, you can now (at least it works for me :) ):

http://stackoverflow.com/a/21587130/328184

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not.  I actually requested this feature on the bug tracker a while back but I can't seem to find it.  IIRC, it has to do with the fact that you'd have to be running the code within a particular isolate, which at the moment is not possible.  In javascript, everything is global so there is a fundamental difference.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. And, also stimulates a whole collection of new questions. However, I will ask them separately. Thanks very much.

Comment: Here is the bug that requests a REPL: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4409

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if it has the Dart VM... I run Dartium but I guess that it can be similar!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XajbEHFd35OFRJSU5hR0FPZlE/edit?usp=sharing

You have to change in the context menu.
If this answer doesn't work for you I'm sorry...

Comment: The link is dead.