# Is there anyway to invoke a Dart REPL on a website, when using Dartium?

Tags: dart, dartium

I now know that I can't interact with [Dart via the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793357/is-it-possible-to-enter-dart-code-directly-into-the-chromium-dev-tools-console), but I was hoping that there may be another way to invoke a REPL within Dartium.

Basically, what I would like to be able to do is:
1. Go to a website in Dartium
2. Invoke some sort of Dart REPL
3. Mess about with the DOM, CSS etc., using Dart commands, rather than Javascript.

Is this possible at all? Or, is the Dart development model all Edit/Refresh?

Cheers
Andy

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Dev tools in Dartium will now let you do this very nicely.

Comment: That's great. However, I am obviously doing something wrong. I downloaded Dart & Dartium. When I go to e.g. this page, Observatory says Dart not running. How do I get the VM running?

Comment: Access a web site that has Dart code on it? So, for example, in the editor, create a new project. Click "Run in Dartium" on the .dart file that it creates. Open Dev Tools in Dartium.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But, is there no way to fire up the Dart VM for any site?  I like the fact that a REPL now exists, but it doesn't - yet - answer my need to be able to use Dart to hack about with any site, rather than e.g. injecting jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Dart edit model is Edit/Refresh.
Maybe you are looking for something like http://try.dartlang.org/